# Why does R# tell me "Cannot resolve assembly System.Drawing" when I am referencing System.Drawing?

Tags: resharper, assemblies, system.drawing, resx, publickeytoken

When I run "Inspect > Code Issues in Solution", R# tells me "Cannot resolve assembly System.Drawing" and points to this line of xml in a *.resx file:

```
<assembly alias="System.Drawing" name="System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

I looked at my System.Drawing assembly in my project's list of References. It is version 3.5.0.0, not 2.0.0.0, so I changed the version number in the xaml in the .resx file from 2.0 to 3.5. That still elicited the same warning from R#, though.

So then I thought maybe it was the PublicKeyToken that was the culprit; so I changed that value from "b03f5f7f11d50a3a" to "969db8053d3322ac" (as found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e16d4b5-9492-44e4-a771-56fa16e43723/how-do-i-find-out-the-publikeytoken-for-systemdrawing-in-netcf35?forum=winembmngdapp)); but then the project wouldn't even build; I got:

*Invalid Resx file. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.*

Although these "issues" exist, the app seems to be working okay - the image that follows the assembly alias:

```
<data name="pictureBox1.Image" type="System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
    <value>
        blee blah bloo
</value>
  </data>
```

...displays fine.

Still, when R# raises its finger, it makes me nervous; how can I rectify this flubup?

**NOTE**: This is a Visual Studio 2008 Windows CE/Compact Framework app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the resx file in one of my C# projects:

[image]

Once I installed the relevant reference (System.Windows.Forms etc) - for that project - that particular resharper issue went away: